# Add external path to JBoss 4 classpath settings

Tags: java, jboss, internationalization, struts1

I've inherited an application that runs on a JBoss 4.2.1.GA deployment cluster.  The application is a hybrid of technologies, but the primary View technologies used are Struts 1 & Struts 2 (they co-exist).

I am struggling with understand how the application is built and deployed.  The app using i18n for the front end, and uses the standard `bean:message` tags to retrieve the translations:

Ex:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>
<input type="text" name="searchFilter" id="searchFilterId" value="<bean:message key="ng.searchfor"/>"
```

Additionally, the app has a bunch of application.properties files (for each translation).

However, when the EAR is built and deployed, the application*.properties files are not packaged in the WAR/EAR.  Rather they are stripped and copied to an external shared folder on the server (one to which all the nodes in the cluster have access).  The concept, I believe, is that the properties can be written to a central location, and loaded/reloaded on the fly by the application.

I don't understand, however, how struts manages to load these translation files.  From my understanding, the application*.properties files need to be on the application classpath such that struts can find them.

The `struts-config.xml` file has no additional information:

Nor does the web.xml:

```
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>config</param-name>
         <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>debug</param-name>
         <param-value>0</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>detail</param-name>
         <param-value>2</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>chainConfig</param-name>
         <!-- We overide the default chain-config.xlm file to add the chain command in charge of the audit trail.-->
         <param-value>/WEB-INF/chain-config.xml</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
```

So my only conclusion is that somehow these application.properties file (stored in a path external to jboss) is mapped to the classpath somehow such that the classloader can automatically find them.

But I can't seem to find that directive/configuration instruction anywhere.

Does JBoss 4 have a config file that would allow me to add paths to the classloader?  I found references to using modules in JB 7+, but haven't been able to find anything for JB4.  Or is there a way to configure struts to load it's application.properties files from outside the classpath?

Comment: What a classloader are you talking? Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @RomanC I wrote the question too late at night when I was too tired.  I rewrote the entire thing this morning; I hope it provides a lot more clarity now.

Comment: You can load properties using Properties API, struts can only load resource bundles